# Redhawk IDE will not display Components

Tags: ide, components, redhawksdr

When I launch the **REDHAWK IDE** via Eclipse, I cannot see the installed components (SigGen, fastFilter, etc). I can see the components just fine if I use the command line to create a project. I'm convinced it has to be a path or variable issues, but I just don't know what to reconfigure.

I'm using REDHAWK Version 2.1.0 and on CentOS7

OSSIEHOME is set to the /usr/local/redhawk/core

SDRROOT is set to /var/redhawk/sdr

Any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using REDHAWK Version 2.1.0 and on CentOS7

Comment: Can you clarify where you don't see components? In the Redhawk Explorer view, under Target SDR? In the palette of the Chalkboard Sandbox diagram?

Comment: I should have clarified that.  I believe I would call it under the palette in the Chalkboard sandbox.  When the IDE boots and I have the Chalkboard sandbox open, there are sections to the right for "Palette", "Components" and "Workspace".  Both "Components" and "Workspace" are blank.  I had a previous installation that booted with the prepackaged components showing in this location. But when I recently reinstalled the Redhawk software, these fields are now blank.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by reinstalling and including every Redhawk package that I could find using "yum list redhawk*"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it turns out I was using a Java version higher than 8 which is not supported by RedHawk.  Make sure you use Java 8 to launch the IDE otherwise it does not work.  Submitted a DR but because JDK8 still supported they do not feel the need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [official installation instructions](https://redhawksdr.org/2.3.0/manual/installation/) for RedHawk 2.3.0 on Centos 7.9 and had this same issue, I fixed it by opening a terminal in the Redhawk installation directory and running

```sh
sudo yum install redhawk-basic-components-2.3.0-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

After which the components appeared in the IDE without a restart